# Where can I find an app to serve the Stackexchange Data Dump content in a friendly UI?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, data-dump

I am working with an organization that is teaching coding to inmates in a prison. Our students do not have a lot; passion, dedication, commitment, intelligence, but they do not have internet access.

The StackExchange Data Dumps could be an awesome resource for us, but there doesn't seem to be any open source web apps for querying the content like a normal online user might. The projects built for the Data Dumps seem to be meta-analytics-type tools only.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If we have to, our students will build this for themselves, but I'd love to save them the time.

Comment: How much work are you willing to put into it? The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) is [open source](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer), but it would likely require some modification (not to mention setting up an appropriately-configured server) to work locally.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here. I was amazed at how much I struggled to find this. But its StackDump!

[Stackdump, an offline browser for StackExchange sites](https://stackapps.com/questions/3610/stackdump-an-offline-browser-for-stackexchange-sites)

Haven't gotten it working yet because of other issues. But this definitely is the tool I've been looking for.